# How do you identify iptables-marked packets in the user-space implementation of a tun device?

Tags: vpn, iptables, tun

I have some custom VPN code, written in C, which uses a Linux tun device.

Is it possible for this user-space code to see iptables marks that were attached to packets?  Or do those marks not propagate as far as a tun interface?

Comment: My 2 cents: you may try iptables "NFLOG" rules on tun device to explicitly send packets to userspace for further analyzing http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables-extensions.man.html#lbDI